# How does linker find shared library without SONAME

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, elf

if I create a shared library without a SONAME like this

```
gcc -shared libfoo.o -o libfoo.so
```

and link against it,
how does the linker find my shared library?

Is the filename `libfoo.so` considered as default SONAME by the linker?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're right. Here what ld man pages say:

> -soname=name
>
> When  creating  an  ELF  shared  object, set the internal DT_SONAME field to the specified name.  When an executable is linked with a
>              shared object which has a DT_SONAME field, then when the executable is run the dynamic linker will attempt to load the shared  object
>              specified by the DT_SONAME field rather than the using the file name given to the linker.