# CPack RPM puts library both in "provides" and "requires" lists

Tags: dependencies, rpm, cpack

My product **foo** is composed of a library: `libfoo.so` and an executable: `foo`, which depends on `libfoo.so` and on a third-party `libbar.so`.

I use CPack to get a RPM of **foo** which contains `lib/libfoo.so` and `bin/foo`.

But in the end I can't install the package: `rpm -ivh` complains about a needed dependency: `libfoo.so`.

I understand that automatic dependency resolution finds that `foo` needs `libfoo.so` but the purpose of installing the package is to provide that library.

If I disable automatic dependency resolution with [`CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_AUTOREQ`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/rpm.html#variable:CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_AUTOREQ), the RPM looses `libbar.so` dependency as well.

How should I configure CPack in order to keep external dependencies but not internal ones?

Answer (score 1):

My Bad.

Automatic dependency detection was fooled by wrong file permissions: both `bin/foo` and `lib/libfoo.so` had `rw-rw-r--` permissions, missing `x`.

To fix the issue, I just added `USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS` flag to CMake `install(DIRECTORY ...)` directive:

```
install(DIRECTORY    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
        DESTINATION  "${INSTALL_DIR}"
        USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS)
install(DIRECTORY    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
        DESTINATION  "${INSTALL_DIR}"
        USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS)
```

Comment: A similar question, [“Missing” lib for rpm install when it is present in rpm file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27445918/45249), gives a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39819960/45249)