# Forcing a binary to use a specific (newer) version of a shared library (.so)

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, elf, dynamic-linking, ldd

I have an older binary executable (utserver, closed source) that I'm trying to run on a system running Fedora 22.

utserver wants openssl_1.0.0 - F22 provides openssl_1.0.1k

I made two symlinks:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1k /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1k /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

But trying to run utserver complains about library version:

```
$ ./utserver
./utserver: /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by ./utserver)
./utserver: /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by ./utserver)
```

OK, so it's looking for a version string. I edited the utserver ELF to change the string OPENSSL_1.0.0 to OPENSSL_1.0.1 but I get the same error (`OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found)

objdump and readelf both show OPENSSL_1.0.1 present in version area of libssl.so.1.0.1:

```
$ objdump -p /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1 | grep OPENSSL
3 0x00 0x066a2b21 OPENSSL_1.0.1
4 0x00 0x02b21533 OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC
0x02b21533 0x00 07 OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC
```

so now I'm confused as to what utserver is actually checking for. I suspect it's seeing OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC and failing. If I add the _EC in the ELF I get a seg fault, presumably because now my offsets are all wrong.

```
$ readelf -d ./utserver 
readelf: Error: Unable to seek to 0x15da90000000 for string table
readelf: Error: no .dynamic section in the dynamic segment

Dynamic section at offset 0x154fb8 contains 34 entries:
```

Is there any way to tell ld-linux to force load OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC and/or a reference to modifying ELF offsets? Would be much appreciated.

Yes, I know I can find a version of openssl_1.0.0 packaged somewhere, but that's one library I'd rather not revert if I don't have to.

Comment: Take a look at [**“soname” option for building shared library**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637841/soname-option-for-building-shared-library).

Comment: Thanks David, when I use readelf -d libssl.so.1.0.1 I get "libssl.so.10" for the soname. My executable is looking for "OPENSSL_1.0.1" which I think is a version string in the so and not the soname...?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to tell `ld-linux` to force load `OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC`

No.

There is a *reason* why the symbol versions have been changed: the old and new symbols are *not* [ABI-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). You *must* recompile the executable to use the new symbols, or (easier) you *must* provide `libssl.so.1.0.0` (which can be installed and co-exist with already installed `libssl.so.1.0.1k`).

> that's one library I'd rather not revert if I don't have to.

You don't have to revert anything (and reverting will break all the programs that want the new version).

Simply providing the `libssl.so.1.0.0` from an old package will make old programs (that require it) use that file, while new programs (which require `libssl.so.1.0.1k`) will continue to use `libssl.so.1.0.1k`.

Comment: I am surprised that OpenSSL is misusing the library versioning to such an extent then. If it isn't ABI compatible it should be a new major version, not a patch level update.

Answer (score 0):

**easy fix in debian:**

add oldstable/jessie to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://mi.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mi.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free
```

update your apt db:

```
sudo apt update
```

and then simply:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0.0/jessie
```

Answer (score 0):

The `libssl1.0.0` Debian package contains the missing libraries (the `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` and `libssl.so.1.0.0`), and can be downloaded from this page: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/ (e.g. for x86 architecture the link would be http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.10_amd64.deb).

On a Debian-based system (e.g. Ubuntu), one can install the downloaded package with

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.10_amd64.deb
```

On a **non**-Debian system one can (i) extract the content of the package with

```
ar x libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.10_amd64.deb
```

(ii) get the required library files, and (iii) place them in a location where the executable in question can find them.