# How to create a shared library out of a C program?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a shared library out of my C program. How do I do that?
I think you need the program, so here it is:

```
#include "defs.h"
#include "externs.h"


int CheckPrime(int K){

int J;

J = 2;
while (1)  {
  if (Prime[J] == 1)
     if (K % J == 0)  {
        Prime[K] = 0;
        return 0;
     }
  J++; 
break;
}


Prime[K] = 1; 
}
```

I've also made a Makefile, can I do it in it?:

```
# -----------------------------------
# ------ executable rule  -----------
# -----------------------------------
app : app.o
    -gcc -g  app.o -o app

# ---------------------------------------------------
# ------ intermeditate object files rule (.o) -------
# ---------------------------------------------------
app.o : main.c
     -gcc -g -c main.c -o app.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply add the `-shared` flag to *gcc*.

```
gcc -g -shared app.o -o libapp.so
```

you can also use the [`soname`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613602/1983495) option to control versioning, example

```
gcc -g -shared -Wl,-soname,libapp.1.0.0.so app.o -o libapp.so
```

to indicate it's version 1.0.0 API.