# Where is the .so file saved after compiling a shared library in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I am attempting to create a shared object using Eclipse CDT and g++, this is the command I am running to compile:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname=example -o "libProject_Name" ./src/source.o
```

I am receiving the "libProject_Name" file in my project's debug folder upon compilation, but I cannot find where the example.so file is located. Am I wrong in assuming this should be appearing in the same folder?

Comment: Handy reading: [What is the 'soname' option for building shared libraries for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637841/what-is-the-soname-option-for-building-shared-libraries-for)